# Add a subview(ShareView) but nothing happens when touching a button on it

Tags: ios, swift, events, uiview, touch

Add a subview(ShareView) but nothing happens when touching a button(coverBtn) on it if I `shareVC.addsubView(self)` in `func showShareView ()`

But If  `superView.addSubview(coverBtn)` and `superView.addSubview(sharePanel)` separately, everything will be fine.

```
import UIKit

class ShareView: UIView {

    weak var shareVC: UINavigationController?


    // UI
    private lazy var coverView: UIView! = {
        let coverView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        return coverView
    }()

    // transluscent cover
    private lazy var coverBtn: UIButton! = {

        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height)
        let coverBtn = UIButton(frame: frame)
        print ("UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds = \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)")
        coverBtn.alpha = 0.2
        coverBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        coverBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ShareView.pressCoverBtn), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return coverBtn
    }()
    let panelHeight: CGFloat = 215
    // share panel
    private lazy var sharePanel: UIView! = {

        // panel size
        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let h = 215
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, bounds.height, bounds.width, self.panelHeight)
        let sharePanel: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
        sharePanel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)

        // label
        let labelHeight: CGFloat = 30
        let labelWidth: CGFloat = 100
        let labelY: CGFloat = 20
        let labelFrame = CGRectMake(sharePanel.frame.width/2-labelWidth/2, labelY, labelWidth, labelHeight)
        let label  = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)
        label.text = "分享到"
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        sharePanel.addSubview(label)


        // share buttons
        let marginW: CGFloat = 80
        let btnInv: CGFloat = 20
        let btnCnt: CGFloat = 3
        let btnsY = label.frame.maxY + 15
        let btnA = (sharePanel.frame.width - 2*marginW - (btnCnt-1)*btnInv)/btnCnt
        let wcFrame = CGRectMake(marginW, btnsY, btnA, btnA)
        let pyqFrame = CGRectMake(wcFrame.maxX+btnInv, btnsY, btnA, btnA)
        let wbFrame = CGRectMake(pyqFrame.maxX+btnInv, btnsY, btnA, btnA)

        let wcBtn = UIButton(frame: wcFrame)
        let pyqBtn = UIButton(frame: pyqFrame)
        let wbBtn = UIButton(frame: wbFrame)

        wcBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "share_wx"), forState: .Normal)
        pyqBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "share_pyq"), forState: .Normal)
        wbBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "share_wb"), forState: .Normal)

        sharePanel.addSubview(wcBtn)
        sharePanel.addSubview(pyqBtn)
        sharePanel.addSubview(wbBtn)

        // cancel button
        let ccW = sharePanel.frame.width/2
        let ccH: CGFloat = 50
        let ccFrame = CGRectMake(sharePanel.frame.width/2-ccW/2, wcBtn.frame.maxY+10, ccW, ccH)
        let cancelBtn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: ccFrame)
        cancelBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "kkk"), forState: .Normal)
        cancelBtn.setTitle("取消", forState: .Normal)
        cancelBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ShareView.pressCoverBtn), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        sharePanel.addSubview(cancelBtn)

        return sharePanel
    }()




    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

//    override init(){
//        super.init()
//    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addCustomView(self)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCustomView (superView: UIView) {
        superView.addSubview(coverBtn)
        superView.addSubview(sharePanel)
    }

    @objc func pressCoverBtn() {
        print("press cover btn\n")
        hideShareView()
    }

    func showShareView () {
        self.addCustomView((shareVC?.view)!)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            () -> Void in
            self.sharePanel.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - self.panelHeight, self.sharePanel.frame.width, self.panelHeight)
            })

    }
    func hideShareView() {
        coverBtn.removeFromSuperview()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            () -> Void in
            self.sharePanel.frame  = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height, self.sharePanel.frame.width, self.panelHeight)
            }) { (finish)-> Void in
                self.removeFromSuperview()
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the 'Debug View Hierarchy' to focus on layers so that you can see if there is a view over the button blocking it
'Debug view Hierarchy' will give you 3d view of every layer
it is situated in bottom bar

[image: this image]

Also, you are adding both the views to the superview, try to add 'coverBtn' button to the 'sharePanel' view and then add the view to the super view, this will create button layer above the 'sharePanel' view

Comment: Every element is shown in `Debug view Hierarchy` , the only problem is `coverBtn` button not respond to touch event if `shareVC.addsubView(self)`. The `coverBtn` button is design to below `sharePanel` (`shareView` contains `coverBtn` and `sharePanel`,  and `coverBtn` is below sharePanel), and I have already add `coverBtn` to `shareView`

Comment: dont add the button below a view, doing so will cover up the response are of button.
Add 'coverBtn' above the 'sharePanel' then add 'sharePanel' to 'shareView' also there is no need to add 'coverBtn' again to 'shareView'